# "No native symbols in symbol file" when debugging C# DLL executed from VFP9 in VS2013

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, com, visual-foxpro

I had to port a exe program to dll for usage with VFP, this is my first time learning about debugging process, i have checked a lot of documentation and threads here.

West-wind was a big help too (http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetfromVfp/DotNetFromVfp_ComplexObjects.asp)

The thing is, now i am doing all output debugging process via txt files, which is really annoying, so i tried to debug the dll directly, but i step into this error

Output Windows says

```
x86\Debug\dzg.dll: No native symbols in symbol file.
```

and in the IDE:

```
The Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been loaded for this document
```

I have tried to nuke, build, rebuild, sign and regasm /codebase, gacutil /i dzg.dll etc. (I checked all the exe were for .net 3.5)

also checked admin permissions on both vs2013, and vfp, command prompt when doing the registrations, etc

but i just can't load the symbol file to debug it

Have anybody done this before? most reports of "No Native Symbols" are for ASP or C++ but not with VFP

I really have tried all the solutions posted on this website, MSDN and other sites, but i really got into a dead end.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No native symbols in symbol file

That's accurate, the symbol file for a C# class library doesn't have any *native* symbols, only managed ones.  This went wrong because you selected the wrong debugging engine in the Tools + Attach to Process dialog.  Click the Select button and tick a managed debugger.

The much easier way to do this is by configuring the debugger in your C# project.  Use the Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Select the "Start external program" radio button and select the VFP executable.  Now you can simply press F5 to start debugging.

Comment: I am not sure if i should mark Hans Passant comment as answer or not, but certainly i found a workaround.

if i open VFP manually and after then attach VS to it manually, i can debug the code on time and symbols and breakpoints will work fine, but if i start the debug process from VS2013 (by "Start External program" it will just not work

There's the fix

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i should mark Hans Passant comment as answer or not, **but certainly i found a workaround.**

if i open VFP manually and after then attach VS to it *manually*, i can debug the code on time and symbols and breakpoints will work fine, **but if i start the debug process from VS2013 (by "Start External program" it will just not work**